# Retention Rate within Cohort

Tags: retention

I want some cohort analysis on a userbase. We have 2 tables "signups" and "sessions", where users and sessions both have a "date" field. I'm looking to formulate a query that yields a table of numbers (with some blanks) that shows me: a count of users who  created an account on a particular day and ho also have a session created , indicating that he returned on that day, 3rd day, 7th day and 14 day.

created_at   d1     d3     d7      d14
05/07/2007   12     *       *      *
04/07/2007   49    21      1       2
03/07/2007   45    30      *       3
02/07/2007    47    41    18      12

...
In this case, 47 users who  created an account  on 2/07/2007 returned after  3 days(d3)

Can I perform this in a single MySQL query?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can:

```
Select Signups.date as created at, 
count (distinct case when datediff(sessions.date, signups.date)=1 then signups.users else null end) as d1,
count (distinct case when datediff(sessions.date, signups.date)=3 then signups.users else null end) as d3,
count (distinct case when datediff(sessions.date, signups.date)=7 then signups.users else null end) as d7,
count (distinct case when datediff(sessions.date, signups.date)=14 then signups.users else null end) as d14 from signups
left join sessions using(users)
group by 1
```

Comment: i didnt get success please clarify